# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app' in line 24 of build.gradle

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gradle, build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Where:
Build file '/media/amal/HDD/flutter_projects/listdemo/android/app/build.gradle' line: 24
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.PluginCrashReporter

[this is the build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XikC5.png)

[this is the error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBzwN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open android/.gradle and Delete Version Folder( 6.7 in my case)
Step 2:Open android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties ,Then change
Distributionurl="https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip"
To
Distributionurl="https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip

By Doing this you are downgraded the Gradle version,And this Solves the error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).